# Laravel, mi form no llama al controllador

Tags: laravel

estoy con un simple form, que no llama a la ruta ( y luego al controller). He probado con `dd()` pero ni llega, y no me da ningun error.

`web.php`

```
...
Route::group(['prefix' => '/mensaje'],function() {
    Route::post('/usuario_no_activo','MensajeController@envioDesdePaginaUsuarioInactivo')->name('mensaje.usuario-no-activo');
});
...
```

`MensajeController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\TipoMensaje;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MensajeController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function envioDesdePaginaUsuarioInactivo(Request  $request){
        $tipoMensaje = TipoMensaje::usuarioNoActivo();
        $user = auth()->user();

        $contenidoMensaje = $request->contenido;

        $nuevoMensaje = $user->mensajes()->create([
            'contenido'=>$contenidoMensaje,
            'tipo_mensaje_id'=>$tipoMensaje->id
        ]);
        if ($nuevoMensaje){
            Session::flash('mensaje', 'Mensaje enviado correctamente!');
            Session::flash('alert-class', 'success');

        }
        else{
            Session::flash('mensaje', 'Error al enviar el mensaje!');
            Session::flash('alert-class', 'danger');
        }

        return back();

    }
}
```

`template.blade.html`

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    
        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }} - @yield('title')</title>
    
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('css/datatable.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!-- Icono  (no funciona)-->
        <link rel="icon" href="{{asset('storage/sistema/iconos/arbol.jpg')}}">
    
    </head>
    
    <style>
        body{
            /* background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #5fd185 0%, #7edb76 100%); */
        }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
        @if(Session::has('mensaje'))
            <div class="alert alert-{{Session::get('alert-class')}} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                {{Session::get('mensaje')}}
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        @endif
        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    
    @yield('js')
    <!-- jQuery Modal -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
    </body>
    </html>



pagina hija del template `default.page.blade`


@extends('errores.template')

@section('title','Usuario no activo')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1 class="text-danger text-center">
                {{$mensaje}}
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <button id="btn_abrir_modal" class="btn btn-warning">
                Enviar mensaje
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 text-center mt-2">
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
               onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                <b>Cerrar Sesión</b>
            </a>
        </div>

        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            @csrf
        </form>

        <div class="modal fade" id="mediumModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mediumModalLabel"
             aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body" id="mediumBody">
                        <div>
                            <p>Tú correo: <b>{{auth()->user()->email}}</b></p>
                            <p>Contenido del mensaje: </p>
                            <form action="{{route('mensaje.usuario-no-activo')}}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                @method('post')
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea style="resize: none;" id="contenido_mensaje" rows="10" class="form-control" name="contenido" placeholder="Contenido del mensaje"></textarea>
                                    <label id="counter_char"></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_enviar_mensaje">
                                        Enviar mensaje
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group text-center">
                                    <a
                                            class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                                            rel="modal:close"
                                            href="#close-modal"
                                    >
                                        Cerrar ventana
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('js')
    <script>
        var maxChar = 200;
        var currentChar = 0;

        $(document).ready(function (){
           $('#counter_char').text(currentChar+'/'+maxChar);
            checkSendButton(currentChar);

        });


        $('#btn_abrir_modal').on('click',function () {
                $('#mediumModal').modal('show');
                $('#mediumBody').modal('show');
        })

        $('#contenido_mensaje').on('keypress keydown keyup',function (e){
            let contenido = $(this).val();
            let  keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
            currentChar = contenido.length;


            //intenta escribir una vez alcanzado el maximo y no está borrando (no debe escribir)
            if (currentChar >= maxChar && keyCode!==8){
                setCurrentCharLength(currentChar);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            //intenta escribir sin haber alcanzado el max char (si debe escribir)
            else if (currentChar <= maxChar && keyCode!==8){
                setCurrentCharLength(currentChar);
            }
            //intenta borrar, siempre debe poder
            else if (keyCode === 8){
                setCurrentCharLength(currentChar);
            }
            //rechaza la accion
            else{
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            checkSendButton(currentChar);

        });


        //Setea la var de n chars del textarea
        function setCurrentCharLength(n) {
            currentChar = n;
            $('#counter_char').text(currentChar+'/'+maxChar);
        }

        //Activa/desactiva boton enviar
        function checkSendButton(n) {

            if (currentChar === 0 || currentChar>maxChar){
                $('#btn_enviar_mensaje').attr('disabled',true)
            }
            else{
                $('#btn_enviar_mensaje').attr('disabled',false)
            }
        }
    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: ¿`mensaje.usuario_no_activo`? (en el action del form)

Comment: el route name de la ruta a la que tiene que ir

Comment: Me refiero a que debería ir con guiones bajos, no con guiones medios.